# Memory Error when training Multinomial Naive Bayes model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, out-of-memory, nltk

The training portion of my code can handle data in the order of magnitude of `10^4` but given that my whole dataset consists of ~500,000 comments I would like to train it with much more data. I seem to run out of memory when running the trainer with 100,000 reviews.

My `get_features` function seems to be the culprit.

```
data = get_data(limit=size)
data = clean_data(data)
all_words = [w.lower() for (comment, category) in data for w in comment]
word_features = []
for i in nltk.FreqDist(all_words).most_common(3000):
    word_features.append(i[0])
random.shuffle(data)

def get_features(comment):
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
        features[word] = (word in set(comment))  # error here
    return features

# I can do it myself like this:
feature_set = [(get_features(comment), category) for
                (comment, category) in data]

# Or use nltk's Lazy Map implementation which arguable does the same thing:
# feature_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(get_features, data, labeled=True)
```

Running this for `100,000` reviews eats up all of my 32GB of RAM and eventually crashes with a `Memory Error`, at the `features[word] = (word in set(comment))` line.

**What can I do to alleviate this problem?**

EDIT: I have significantly reduced the number of features: I now use only the top 3000 most common words as features - this has significantly improved performance (for obvious reasons). I also corrected a small mistake pointed out by @Marat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: this code has many potential flaws so I expect few iterations to get to the root cause.

## Parameters mismatch:

```
# defined with one parameter
def get_features(comment):
    ...

# called with two
... get_features(comment, word_features), ...
```

## Suboptimal word lookup:

```
# set(comment) executed on every iteration
for word in word_features:
    features[word] = (word in set(comment))

# can be transformed into something like:
word_set = set(comment)
for word in word_features:
    features[word] = word in word_set

# if typical comment length is < 30, list lookup is faster
for word in word_features:
    features[word] = word in comment
```

## Suboptimal feature computing:

```
# it is cheaper to set few positives than to check all word_features
# also MUCH more memory efficient
from collections import defaultdict
...
def get_features(comment):
    features = defaultdict(bool)
    for word in comment:
        features[word] = True
    return features
```

## Suboptimal feature storage:

```
# numpy array is much more efficient than a list of dicts
# .. and with pandas on top it's even nicer:
import pandas as pd
...
feature_set = pd.DataFrame(
    ({word: True for word in comment}
      for (comment, _) in data),
    columns = word_features
).fillna(False)
feature_set['category'] = [category for (_, category) in data]
```

Comment: Point 1) was due to me copying and pasting some old code. I agree with the rest, though I suspect only the last 2 points will have a real impact; I will investigate. Also, I have made some changes, so I will make an edit. Thanks.